# Cron job in Magento 1.9

Tags: xml, magento

here is how i am trying to set up cron job:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Name>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Namespace_Name>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <name>
            <class>Namespace_Name_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>name_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </name>
        <name_mysql4>
            <class>Namespace_Name_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <name>
                    <table>name</table>
                </name>
            </entities>
        </name_mysql4>
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <Namespace_Name>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>5 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>name/observer::methodName</model>
            </run>
        </Namespace_Name>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
</config>
```

My extension Namespace_Name working fine, models, blocks,observer included fine. Just cron job not working. Please help me, what i am doing wrong ? I want run code in methodName every 5 min.

**Currently in my CPanel i see cron.php has been sheduled every 5 min.**
cron_schedule table is empty
methodName contain Mage::log('cron working fine') But there is not log files in var/log folder

Answer (score 0):

issue with config.xml just chek

```
<?xml verssion="1.0" ?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Namespace_Name>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Namespace_Name>
</modules>
<global>
    ...
<!-- need to define model -->
<models>
    <name>
        <class>Namespace_Name_Model></class>
    </name>
</models>

</global>
    <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <namespace_name>
        <schedule><cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <run><model>name/observer::methodName</model></run>
        </namespace_name>
    </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: Hello Amit, thank you for answer. I have described model as you say but cron job not working. Maybe i have to configure my server some how ?

Comment: on my server configurations i have installed cron job every 15 min but methodName not runing

Comment: Check your `cron_schedule` table to see if the job has been scheduled. You should see `job_code` labeled as `namespace_name`

Comment: unfortunately this table is empty

Comment: in my cpanel i see cron.php has been scheduled every 15 min